# jQuery - How to improve the logic for toggling inline css and class name while clicking activated buttons and hovering non-activated buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got an issue when I am trying to implement toggle inline css and class name while clicking buttons. So buttons have same background colour, when I hover or click on each of them, their own colours will be displayed. The below code is just my simple logic, so I simplify the code.

Let me start it with html first:

```
<div id="filters">
    <button class="filter" data-color="#A52A2A"></button>
    <button class="filter" data-color="#EE82EE"></button>
    <button class="filter" data-color="#FF7F50"></button>
    <button class="filter" data-color="#1E90FF"></button>
</div>
```

and of course css:

```
button{
    background: transparent;
}
.filter{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
}
```

What I am trying to do is pulling the dynamic colours and assign them to data attributes because I am going to read those dynamic colours in jQuery.

The below is my jQuery implementation:

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var $color;
    if($("#filters button").hasClass('current')){
        $color = $(this).data('color');

        //remove background color and class while clicking on any buttons.
        $('#filters button').not(this).css('background', '').removeClass('current'); 
        $(this).css('background-color', $color).toggleClass('current');
    }else{
        $(this).css('background-color', $color).addClass('current');
    }
});


$('button').hover(
    function(){
    $color = $(this).data('color');
       $(this).css('background', $color);
    },
    function(){
       if($(this).hasClass('current')){
           $(this).css('background-color', $color);
       }else{
           $(this).css('background', '');
      }
});
```

It is fine when hovering buttons, they display their own colours successfully. Also when I click on buttons, they are able to be activated and show their own colours. I also want to turn off "current" button when I click again.

However, I got an issue when I am trying to click the activated button again. I only can remove "current" class assigned to "current" button. The colour is still on the activated button, I think that's because this:

```
$('button').hover(
        function(){
        $color = $(this).data('color');
           $(this).css('background', $color);
        },
        function(){
           if($(this).hasClass('current')){
               $(this).css('background-color', $color);
           }else{
               $(this).css('background', '');
          }
    });
```

Because I am still hovering on the button, the colour is not removed. The colour is removed after leaving that button.

I don't get an better idea for removing inline css "background colour" on the activated button. So, I am wondering is there something wrong with my logic? or is there any better ways to implement this?

I attached my fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/softstar126/tow7n1d2/11/

Could some one support me with better ideas or hints? This simple logic actually has driven me crazy.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more modular way of doing it.

```
var $color;
$('#filters button').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $color = $(this).data('color');
        $(this).css('background', $color);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if(!$(this).is('.current')){
            $(this).attr('style', '');
        }
    },
    click: function() {
        $color = $(this).data('color');
        if( $(this).is('.current')){
            $(this).attr('style', '').removeClass('current');
        } else {
            $(this).siblings().attr('style', '').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    }
});
```

Like that you have more control for what is happening during the different events.
using `attr('style', '')` might save you some browser compability issues.
corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tow7n1d2/24/)

Comment: Really thanks for supporting me with you modular way. And it is really more clear and easier to manage them. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You just mixed up a little in the click handler.

```
$('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var $color = $(this).data('color');
    if($(this).hasClass('current')){
        // turning off
        $(this).css('background-color', '').toggleClass('current'); // Changed $color to ''
    }else{
        // turning on
        $('#filters button').not(this).css('background', '').removeClass('current'); // Moved to the else
        $(this).css('background-color', $color).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

And here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zord/tow7n1d2/17/).

Comment: Oh my god!!! I believe that I almost get my own answer after got your idea, I can't believe that it's move this line: 

$('#filters button').not(this).css('background', '').removeClass('current'); 

to the other part.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The logic can really be simplified to this:

on click

- remove all styling;
- if nothing was selected, colour the current button.

This is the updated fiddle with no `hover` part: http://jsfiddle.net/tow7n1d2/15/, which I am sure you can easily add yourself.

Comment: Yes, I can just add your logic in. Thanks for your answer. Really help me a lot.